# Configuring the memcached log level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, logging, memcached

I'm trying to setup memcached logging, so I can keep track of reads/writtes in the cache of my rails app.

Using mac osx for development I installed memcached with homebrew, and starting it with Launchy.

My startup file looks like this (`homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.memcached</string>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/memcached/bin/memcached</string>
    <string>-vv</string>
    <string>localhost</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local</string>

  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/opt/memcached/logs/memcached.log</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/opt/memcached/logs/memcached.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However with regardless how many verbose flags I include in my startup the output is the same, I used [this web](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/ha-memcached-using-logs.html) as resource for different log levels.

I start it like this:

```
lunchy start memcached
```

When I'm tailing logs this is what I get, not very useful :

```
tail -f /usr/local/opt/memcached/logs/memcached.log
<19 send buffer was 9216, now 7456540
<23 send buffer was 9216, now 7456540
<19 server listening (udp)
<22 server listening (udp)
<23 server listening (udp)
<20 server listening (udp)
<21 server listening (udp)
<26 server listening (udp)
<24 server listening (udp)
<25 server listening (udp)
```

Anybody has experience in setting it up, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum level of verbosity is -vvv (each 'v' increases verbosity level). Your current level is -vv, so there is a room for increase up to the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The output posted suggests that nothing is talking to memcached - it's the standard startup logging information. Once something starts talking to memcached you should see lines like:

```
authenticated() in cmd 0x00 is true
<38 GET 16674752-73e0-46d4-b5a7-acc2a2e34834
>38 Writing bin response:
>38   0x81 0x00 0x00 0x00
>38   0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00
>38   0x00 0x00 0x0b 0xb8
>38   0x00 0x22 0x3f 0xff
>38   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>38   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<38 Read binary protocol data:
<38    0x80 0x01 0x00 0x24
<38    0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00
<38    0x00 0x00 0x0c 0x4e
<38    0x00 0x22 0x40 0x01
<38    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<38    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```